# How do I access stdclass varialbles in jQuery / Javsscript / php

Tags: php, jquery

I am running a SOAP call to do payment processing.

The result is not json, when I tried a json decode the error was: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given.

```
 require_once './vendor/autoload.php';
    use MaxMind\MinFraud;

      //for live server use 'www' for test server use 'sandbox'
      $wsdl='https://www.usaepay.com/soap/gate--------/usaepay.wsdl';

      // instantiate SoapClient object as $client
      $client = new SoapClient($wsdl);

      $sourcekey = '[ cut ]';
      $pin = '1234'; 

      // generate random seed value
      $seed=time() . rand();

      // make hash value using sha1 function
      $clear= $sourcekey . $seed . $pin;
      $hash=sha1($clear);

      // assembly ueSecurityToken as an array
      $token=array(
        'SourceKey'=>$sourcekey,
        'PinHash'=>array(
           'Type'=>'sha1',
           'Seed'=>$seed,
           'HashValue'=>$hash
         ),
         'ClientIP'=>$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
      );
```

Above it the config, the processing gets done below and then the final call is there at the end.

How do I access the data in the $res ?

```
        try {   
           $res=$client->runTransaction($token, $Request);

          print_r($res);

        }
        catch (SoapFault $e){
          echo $client->__getLastRequest();
          echo $client->__getLastResponse();
            $location = "https://".$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]."/order-decline.php";
                //header("Location: $location");
          die("runTransaction failed :" .$e->getMessage());
        }
```

Here is the result of the  print_r($res) :

```
     stdClass Object
    (
        [AcsUrl] => 
        [AuthAmount] => 7.21
        [AuthCode] => 229646
        [AvsResult] => Address: Match & 5 Digit Zip: Match
        [AvsResultCode] => Y
        [BatchNum] => 3
        [BatchRefNum] => 46276145
        [CardCodeResult] => Match
        [CardCodeResultCode] => M
        [CardLevelResult] => Unknown Code 
        [CardLevelResultCode] => 
        [ConversionRate] => 0
        [ConvertedAmount] => 0
        [ConvertedAmountCurrency] => 840
        [CustNum] => 0
        [Error] => Approved
        [ErrorCode] => 0
        [isDuplicate] => 
        [Payload] => 
        [RefNum] => 1573277303
        [Result] => Approved
        [ResultCode] => A
        [Status] => Pending
        [StatusCode] => P
        [VpasResultCode] => 
    )
```

My goal is to get the individual variables.  Result code etc.

Comment: You have missed the closing quote mark in your declaration of `$sourcekey`.

Comment: Have you tried using `print_r(json_encode($res, true));`?

Comment: I think you mean decode @GrahamS. ?

Comment: haha yeah, my bad, let me fix that. I meant `print_r(json_decode($res, true));`

Comment: Sorry I posted an incomplete question, its complete now.  I was really tired today @ work that was strange! :)